Kestrel Startup Error - Could not load Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions'
I updated Swashbuckle.AspNetCore from 4.0.1 to 6.5.
Besides changing some classes to the Microsoft.OpenApi.Models pendants I had to change nothing and it worked on my local development machine.
After publishing my Api into the Staging Environment the Kestrel Startup routine throws this error:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception
      Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

In the installation folder the Assembly is present, but in Version 2.2.0.18316 which is the same assembly as it was before I updated to 6.5 and it's also the same version on my local machine where everything works just fine.
Full Trace of Kestrel Startup:
Application startup exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.BuildModel()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.get_ActionDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.DefaultApiVersionDescriptionProvider.EnumerateApiVersions(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at KIBEApi.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Configure>b__0(SwaggerUIOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SwaggerUIBuilderExtensions.UseSwaggerUI(IApplicationBuilder app, Action`1 setupAction)
   at KIBEApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions`1 appSettings)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutoRegisterMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception
      Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.BuildModel()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.get_ActionDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.DefaultApiVersionDescriptionProvider.EnumerateApiVersions(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at KIBEApi.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Configure>b__0(SwaggerUIOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SwaggerUIBuilderExtensions.UseSwaggerUI(IApplicationBuilder app, Action`1 setupAction)
   at KIBEApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions`1 appSettings)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutoRegisterMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.BuildModel()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.get_ActionDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.DefaultApiVersionDescriptionProvider.EnumerateApiVersions(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at KIBEApi.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Configure>b__0(SwaggerUIOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SwaggerUIBuilderExtensions.UseSwaggerUI(IApplicationBuilder app, Action`1 setupAction)
   at KIBEApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions`1 appSettings)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutoRegisterMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.<StartAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at KIBEApi.Program.Main(String[] args)

Any suggestions? What am I missing?

The issue was a missing AssemblyBinding in the Api.exe.config file:
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>

With the update to Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to Version 6.5 there where some changes to the AssemblyBindings which where missing on the Staging environment due to some issues with our deployment process.
After I made sure, the correct *.exe.config file was published to the Staging machine, everything worked fine.
Shoutout to Martin Costello for helping me!
